# как в android изменять цвета элементов интерфейса?

Tags: java, android

Не могу перекрасить элементы в белый цвет, при нажатии на AppCompat, и выборе светлой темы, в макете все становится светлым белым, но ничего не меняется при установке на устройство, все остаётся в темном цвете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставь эту тему для Активити в Манифесте